# Datomic: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to connect to an ddb transactor deployed to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, datomic

I have deployed a datomic transactor to an AWS cloud formation, connected to a DyanmoDB as storage. I'm able to connect to the transactor if I go to my local datomic directory (version 0.9.5.44) and use the repl:

```
=> (def uri "datomic:ddb://us-east-1/datemo/test-db?aws_access_key_id={xxx}&aws_secret_key={yyy}")
=> (def conn (d/connect uri))
#object[datomic.peer.Connection 0x5e5ddfbc "{:unsent-updates-queue 0, :pending-txes 0,:next-t 1000, :basis-t 63, :index-rev 0, :db-id \"test-db-ab4b8028-e25b-4431-b2a2-c7173b4c9918\"}"]
```

If, however, I do the same in my project's repl, it does not work, and instead I get the following error:

> CompilerException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
>   class datomic.ddb_cluster__init,
>   compiling:(form-init1336530578825920965.clj:1:11)

Incidentally, if I try to connect to my usual datomic dev transactor it works just fine. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? The error seems to suggest that the class is not even present...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include both the Datomic Peer library and the AWS SDK as dependencies in your project to connect to a DDB-backed instance.

This section of the documentation: http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html#sec-6-1 contains details of including the AWS SDK.

-Marshall